# Why am I getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')"?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with authorization, in which, when a button is clicked, menuToggler() function is called. But when I try to login I get "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'removeEventListener')", here on this line **document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler").removeEventListener("click", menuToggler);**

```
function menuToggler(){
   document.querySelector(".offcanvas-collapse").classList.toggle("open");
}

useEffect(() => {
      AOS.init({
        duration: 1000,
        easing: "ease",
        once: true,
      });

      window.addEventListener("resize", setWindowsWidth);
      window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction);
      document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler").addEventListener("click", menuToggler);
      document.querySelector(".offcanvas-collapse").addEventListener("click", menuToggler);

      return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("resize", setWindowsWidth);
        window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollFunction);
        document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler").removeEventListener("click", menuToggler);
        document.querySelector(".offcanvas-collapse").removeEventListener("click", menuToggler);
      };
    }, []);
```

Comment: Most components attach event listeners to the `document` or `window` object. I rarely if ever have seen an event listener attached directly to a DOM element. I assume that the element is removed from the DOM by the time the effect cleanup phase fires.\

Comment: Is it correct to do this check "if(document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler") document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler").removeEventListener("click", menuToggler)"?

Comment: why not `document.querySelector('.navbar-toggler')?.removeEventListener(...)`

Comment: You can simply use optional chaining if you wish. Throw a question mark in there before the dot i.e. `document.querySelector(".navbar-toggler")?.removeEventListener("click", menuToggler)`

Comment: You should probably use a `ref` on your `.navbar-toggler` and `.offcanvas-collapse`. How are those defined? Here is an example of attaching an event via a `ref`: [_"How to Remove an Event listener in React"_](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-remove-event-listener)